# how to insert regex to input pattern correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to change the property "pattern" of my input using jquery to a regex pattern.
this is the input :

```
<input id="phone" pattern="[0-9()#&amp;+*-=.]+">
```

I found a way, but the regex does not save the structure when inserted.
this is what i have tried :

```
 var phoneField = jQuery('#phone');
 var phoneRe = "^0(?:[234689]|5[0-689]|7[246789])(?![01])(\d{7})$";
 phoneField.prop("pattern",phoneRe);
```

the output is : `^0(?:[234689]|5[0-689]|7[246789])(?![01])(d{7})$`

expected output is : `^0(?:[234689]|5[0-689]|7[246789])(?![01])(\d{7})$`

to be exact `(d{7})$` should be `(\d{7})$`

Comment: You probably need to escape the escape character, since it is string and not a regex literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape the escape character if the pattern is a string:

```js
console.log(new RegExp("\d").test('5'));  // false
console.log(new RegExp("\\d").test('5')); // true
```

```js
var phoneRe = "^0(?:[234689]|5[0-689]|7[246789])(?![01])(\\d{7})$";
```